# How to compute optical flow using tvl1 opencv function

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I'm trying to find python example for computing optical flow with tvl1 opencv function `createOptFlow_DualTVL1` but it seems that there isn't enough documentation for it.

Could anyone please let me do that? I've used `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` mentioned here http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html but it is not giving me accurate results, will tvl1 good enough and if not is there another method I should look for?

[[EDIT]]

I've some regions come from selective search, I want keep only regions with motion in it, so computing the OF for a given frame and then get the avg in each region could do it. It's also described in this [paper](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gkioxari/ActionTubes/action_tubes.pdf) section 3.1

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like what is in [here](https://github.com/gkioxari/ActionTubes/blob/master/compute_OF/compute_flow.m).

Comment: I've some regions come from selective search, I want keep only regions with motion in it, so computing the OF for a given frame and then get the avg in each region could do it. It's also described in this [paper](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gkioxari/ActionTubes/action_tubes.pdf) section 3.1

Comment: Both Farneback and tvl1 are dense methods that should do the job.  Post your relevant code parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this line(Dense Optical example in http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html):

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs, next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
```

By these:

```
optical_flow = cv2.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create()
flow = optical_flow.calc(prvs, next, None)
```

The parameter descriptions can be found here:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d47/classcv_1_1DualTVL1OpticalFlow.html

Comment: In opencv 4, this is `cv2.optflow.createOptFlow_DualTVL1`, see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/d84/group__optflow.html

Comment: @gerrit is correct but you need to install the `opencv-contrib-python` package to get the `cv2.optflow` module.

Comment: Worth pointing out that CUDA accelerated optical flow is done via the cudaoptflow module. https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d6/d39/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1OpticalFlowDual__TVL1.html