# How to fix opencv import for TVL1 opticalflow algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I'm asking you a very simple question. I want to use the TVL1 function for computing opticalflow with openCV (and python). But here is what I get :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "opticalFlowModel.py", line 50, in computeOpticalFlow
optical_flow = cv2.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create'
```

The problem is that in this topic [How to compute optical flow using tvl1 opencv function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871443/how-to-compute-optical-flow-using-tvl1-opencv-function) , they seems to use the exact same code. I also try this code : [Speed Up Optical Flow algorithm (If applicable) Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209087/speed-up-optical-flow-algorithm-if-applicable-python-opencv) and have the same result.

Here are all my import :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

I'm using OpenCV 4.0.1

Comment: pip install opencv-contrib-python

Comment: I already have installed opencv with extra modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/Rhythmblue/i3d_finetune/issues/2).

The way to call the function is different with the latest openCV version. Here is what to do :

Replace

```
optical_flow = cv2.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create()
```

by

```
optical_flow = cv2.optflow.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create()
```

Comment: optical_flow = cv2.optflow.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create().calc(prvs,next,None)

Comment: @sjcoding I would not recommend this because evry time you will compute an optical flow, this will create a new instance of DualTVL1OpticalFlow. Must use optical_flow = cv2.optflow.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create() and then  current_opt_flow = optical_flow.calc(prvs, next, None) for every new optical flow.